# Snowflake monitoring with Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

How to monitor snowflake using Azure Monitor/azure-loganalytics. I am aware that if we can ship the log data from snowflake to Azure loganalytics , i can run kusto queries and setup alerts and dashboards. The question is what logs/tables data to ship and how (push vs pull).

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far and where it's now working - the community at Stack Overflow would love to help you with specific problems. For a more general discussion, check https://reddit.com/r/snowflake

Comment: The type of logs/table data to unload on Azure from Snowflake will depend on what you want to monitor. But it's easy enough to write that data out to files on Azure storage for example Blob Storage and then analyze them. Also you will find more information here: [Unloading into Microsoft Azure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-azure.html). Could you elaborate the problem so that I can help more.

Comment: Observability. I want to monitor snowflake performance like long running queries , saturation Vs Utilisation , Errors etc and also any metrics that are useful to monitor/alert.  My application traces help me to identify snowflake as a dependency but i want my alerting to be proactive. if my next request is going to fail i want to capture that first hand before the application does.  We are not using tools like newrelic/datadog. And we are also not on snowflake priority plan which does support some out-of-box monitoring.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - I am investigating the possible/feasible approaches to monitor snowflake as yet another service. My plan is 1. Identify the various tables and metrics that are right signals to manage snowflake. 2. ship the identified data to Azure storage or Azure log analytics . 3. setup actionable alerts 4. setup dashboards.